# Finite maximal closed subgroups of Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups

Cross-posted from MSE

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272017/finite-maximal-closed-subgroups-of-lie-groups

$\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}} \newcommand{\K}{\mathcal{K}} \DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\PSU{PSU}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Let $\G$ be a Lie group.

I am interested in finite maximal closed subgroups of $ G $.

I'm guessing that $ \G $ has a finite maximal closed subgroup if and only if $ \G $ is simple and compact. Does anyone have other examples of finite maximal closed subgroups?

Comment: I'd rather guess a compact Lie group has a finite "almost dense" subgroup iff it's semisimple. It's not hard to check it's a necessary condition. But producing such subgroups can require a case-by-case study (esp. in the non-connected case) and there might be exceptions. For a connected Lie group, it can be shown that being compact is a necessary condition. But not for a virtually connected Lie group: if $C_5$ is cyclic of order 5 acting by rotation on the plane, then $C_5$ is "almost dense" in $C_5\ltimes\mathbf{R}^2$. Also among discrete groups (these are Lie) this happens (Tarski monsters).

Comment: @Ycor I don't think semi simple is sufficient for a compact group to have an almost dense subgroup. Here is my logic. Let G be a compact simple group. Then $ G \times G $ is semi simple. However for any finite $ \Gamma $ in $ G \times G $ then the projection onto the second factor say $ \pi_2(\Gamma) $ is finite so $G \times \pi_2(\Gamma) $ is a closed subgroup properly containing $\Gamma $ but  is not all of $G $. So $G \times G$ has no almost dense finite subgroups

Comment: Oh, indeed, you're right: if $G$ is a compact Lie group with a finite almost dense subgroup, then the action of $G/G_0$ in the set of simple factors of $G$ is transitive. In particular, if $G$ is connected, then it has to be simple.

Comment: In fact I think in general by passing to a simply connected cover this proves that simplicity is a necessary condition for having an almost dense finite subgroup (assuming connectedness)

Comment: @Ycor also can you explain your example more. I don't really get it. Why did you pick $C_5$ not $C_3$? And you are just thinking of this as a subgroup of isometries of the plane? Oh wait is it because C_2 and C_4 act on the square lattice and C_3 acts on triangular/ hexagonal lattice?

Comment: Because there are lattices in $\mathbf{R}^2$ that are preserved by $C_3$. While none is preserved by $C_5$. If you have a semidirect product $F\ltimes\mathbf{R}^k$, the closed subgroups containing $F$ are the subgroups of the form $F\ltimes V$ when $V$ is a closed $F$-invariant subgroup of $\mathbf{R}^k$.

Comment: @Ycor can I avoid examples like $V \rtimes F $ for $F $ finite by asking that G be (the real points of) a linear algebraic group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathcal{K}} $Question: When does $ \G $ admit a finite maximal closed subgroup?

Answer : Must be one of the following two cases

1. $ \G $ is compact and simple
2. $ \G $ is not compact in which case $ \G $ cannot be connected and moreover the component group $ \G/\G^\circ $ does not preserve any nontrivial proper closed subgroup (see [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405926/finite-maximal-closed-subgroups-of-lie-groups#comment1040850_405926) from YCor about $ C_5 \ltimes \mathbb{R}^2 $).

From now on I will confine myself to the case that $ \G $ is connected.

In other words I will consider the statement "A connected Lie group $ \G $ has a finite maximal closed subgroup $ G $ if and only if $ \G $ is compact and simple."

The first implication is true.

**Claim 1:
If a connected Lie group $ \G $ has a finite maximal closed subgroup $ G $ then $ \G $ must be compact and simple.**

Proof:
Let $ \G $ be a connected Lie group and $ G $  a finite maximal closed subgroup. Since $ G $ is finite then $ G $ is a compact subgroup of $ \G $ so must be contained in a maximal compact subgroup, call it $ \K $. But $ G $ is a maximal closed subgroup thus we must have that $ \K=\G $ (note that $ \K $ cannot equal $ G $ since $ \K $ is connected (the maximal compact of a connected group is always connected)). So $ \G $ must be compact. If $ \G $ is not simple then there exists some morphism
$$
\pi: \G \to \G_i
$$
with positive dimensional kernel (here $ \G_i $ is basically one of the semisimple factors of $ \G $). Then
$$
\pi^{-1}(\pi(G))
$$
is a closed positive dimensional subgroup containing $ G $, contradicting the fact that $ G $ is a finite maximal closed subgroup. Thus if a connected Lie group $ \G $ has a finite maximal closed subgroup then we can conclude that $ \G $ is simple.

However the reverse implication does not hold: $ SU_{15} $ is an example of a compact connected simple Lie group with no finite maximal closed subgroups.

To see why this is the case it is important to note that

**Claim 2: For a compact connected simple Lie group $ \G $, $ G $ is a finite maximal closed subgroup of $ \G $ if and only if $ G $ is Ad-irreducible and $ G $ is a maximal finite subgroup of $ \G $.**

this follows from Corollary 3.5 of [Sawicki and Karnas - Universality of single qudit gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05780).

Since a finite subgroup of $ SU_n $ is Ad-irreducible if and only if it is a unitary 2-design we have

**Claim 3: $ G $ is a finite maximal closed subgroup of $ SU_n $ if and only if $ G $ is a maximal unitary 2-group in $ SU_n $.**

By inspecting Theorem 3 of [Bannai, Navarro, Rizo, and Pham Huu Tiep - Unitary $t$-groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02507) one immediately determines that $ SU_{15} $ has no finite maximal closed subgroups.

Some of the main examples of finite maximal closed subgroups of $ SU_n $ include the normalizer in $ SU_{p^n} $ of an extra-special group $ p^{2n+1} $. Here $ p $ is an odd prime. There is also a similar construction $ p=2 $. These are known as (complex) Clifford groups. Then there are infinite families of examples relating to the Weil module for $ \operatorname{PSp}_{2n}(3) $ and another family related to $ U_n(2) $. Plus many exceptional cases.

A similar normalizer construction to the above gives finite maximal closed subgroups of all the $ \operatorname{SO}(2^n) $ as normalizers of an extra-special group $ 2^{2n+1} $. This is known as the real Clifford group. For details about real and complex Clifford groups see [Nebe, Rains, and Sloane - Self-Dual Codes and Invariant Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-30731-1).

Comment: Why, if compact, must $G$ be simple or finite? Wouldn't arbitrary finite product of groups of this type also work?

Comment: @Wojowu no see my comment above "I don't think semi simple is sufficient for a compact group to have an almost dense subgroup. Here is my logic..." For example a product like $ A_5 \times A_5 $ in $ SO_3 \times SO_3 $ won't be a maximal closed subgroup since it is contained in $ A_5 \times SO_3 $ (here $ A_5 $ is the icosahedral subgroup of $ SO_3 $).

Comment: Ah apologies, I misread the claim, I thought it asked for maximal (closed and finite). In hindsight that makes little sense to state like that since finite groups are always closed...

Comment: @Wojowu No problem! Thanks for your interest. If you want to know some examples of these finite maximal closed groups it turns out that for $ SU_n $ they are exactly the finite subgroups of $ SU_n $ listed here https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02507

Comment: The integers form a zero dimensional Lie group containing a maximal closed subgroup which is finite, the origin, but the integers are noncompact and they have an infinite group of components.

Comment: @BenMcKay good point I deleted the claim that component group is finite